# 'dgst verify and sign' equivalent with 'RSA_Verify()'

Tags: openssl, rsa, sign, sha, verify

I am using the RSA_verify() function to validate a SHA that I signed by using the openssl program (via a console). RSA_verify() is always returning a non successful validation, so I think that I am sending incorrect parameters to it.

The following console commands are run in Linux Ubuntu with OpenSSL 0.9.8k.

The C functions are compiled for Android, using OpenSSL 1.0.1...c as far as I remember. It's definitely 1.0.1 (we are updating it to avoid the Heartbleed issue).

This is what I do... please forgive any mistake as I am learning this by myself.

1. Generate a private key

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
   ```
2. Extract the public key from the private key

   ```
   openssl rsa -in private.key -out public.key -outform PEM -pubout
   ```
3. Calculate the SHA from a file called permissions and then sign it with the private.key, the output will be a SHA but with RSA encryption (permissions.sign)

   ```
   openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.key -out permissions.sign permissions
   ```
4. Validate a received SHA signature against the permissions file (it's successful in the Ubuntu console)

   ```
   openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.key -signature permissions.sign permissions
   ```
5. I copy the permissions file, the permissions.sign file and the public.key file to the file system in Android.
6. I verify that permissions.sign was created with permissions and with a matching private.key... all of this with my public.key (I don't have the private key in Android).

This is the C function.

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

...

/* Initialize the public key */
RSA *pub_key = RSA_new();

if(NULL == pub_key)
{
   ANDROID_LOGE("RSA_new failed");
   result = 0;
}
else
{
   FILE* fp = fopen(public_key, "r");

   if(NULL == fp)
   {
      ANDROID_LOGE_P("fopen [%s] failed", public_key);
      result = 0;
   }
   else
   {
      /* Read it from the passed path */
      if(PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(fp, &pub_key, NULL, NULL) == NULL)
      {
         ANDROID_LOGE_P("[%s] can't be read", public_key);
         result = 0;
         fclose(fp);
      }
      else
      {
         /* Verify the file and its SHA with the public key */
         int verified = RSA_verify(
             NID_sha256,
             file, /* message digest (message to validate) */
             file_size, /* message size */
             sign, /* signature (signed SHA) */
             sign_size, /* signature size */
             pub_key);
         ANDROID_LOGD("NID_sha256");

         if(verified)
         {
            result = 1;
            ANDROID_LOGD_P("[%s] is valid", file_to_verify);
         }
         else
         {
            ANDROID_LOGE_P("[%s] is NOT valid", file_to_verify);
         }

         fclose(fp);
      }

      RSA_free(pub_key);
   }
}
```

- public_key is a path to public.key
- PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY succeeds
- NID_sha256 is what I think I should use for the verification
- file is a byte array with the contents of permissions
- file_size is the array size of file
- sign is a byte array with the contents of permissions.sign
- sign_size is the array size of sign
- RSA_verify() fails, it returns a 0

So the question is, is it correct to:

- generate the keys with the commands I used,
- sign the permissions file (which generates permissions.sign),
- and then try to verify the files with PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY() and RSA_verify() ?

Are the commands I used for the signing process equivalent to the C functions I used for the verification process?

Please let me know if more info is required or where I could study more about this.

Thanks!

EDIT: I added some error printing after calling RSA_Verify():

ANDROID_LOGE_P("openssl: %s", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));

It prints:

openssl: bad signature

Still investigating.

Comment: perhaps the error is in reading in the files?

Comment: I verified them, the read process is ok. Thx.

Comment: The OpenSSL team recommends you use `EVP_DigestSign*` and `EVP_DigestVerify*` functions. See [EVP Signing and Verifying](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying). The wiki also provides code you can copy/paste to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several missing steps in my reading process for the public key.

The correct commands to generate the private and public keys are as follows:

Generate a private key
 "openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048"

Extract the public key (DER certificate form) from the private key (needed by RSA_SHA_Verify())
 "openssl req -outform DER -new -x509 -key private.key -out public.key -days 30000"

Generate a public key with no certificate info (only needed by "openssl dgst -sha1 -verify ...")
 "openssl x509 -inform DER -in public.key -pubkey -noout > public_no_cert.key"

Sign a file with the private key
 "openssl dgst -sha1 -sign private.key -out permissions.sign permissions"

Verify a file with the public key (no certificate info)
 "openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public_no_cert.key -signature permissions.sign permissions"

Please refer to the documentation on OpenSSL.org for details. I required a X509 DER certificate that was holding the public key to verify the signed SHA with RSA_verify().

An equivalency in command mode to RSA_verify() is:

openssl dgst -sha1 -verify public.key -signature permissions.sign permissions

For code source, please refer to this link:
http://www.bmt-online.org/geekisms/RSA_verify

It does NOT compile at first sight, you have to tweak it. Call the functions in there as follows:

```
   result = sign_data(
         input_file_buffer,
         input_file_size,
         private_key_buffer,
         private_key_size,
         (void**)&signature,
         &signature_size);

   result = verify_data(
         input_file_buffer,
         input_file_size,
         signature_buffer,
         signature_size,
         public_key_buffer,
         public_key_size);
```

Everything has to be in RAM, pass them as pointers.

The signing function expects the pointer to a pointer (**) to save the signed SHA into it. You can later save it into a file.

Tested under Ubuntu openssl 0.9.8k.

If you see that something is missing, please let me know. Thanks for reading!

EDIT: Here's a link to the source code...
http://migsantiago.com/index.php/tutoriales/32-firma-y-valida-archivos-con-openssl